# GNUstep Game Development

Tags: objective-c

Are there any good resources out there for game development in GNU step? I looked at some of the source code for ooLite, but that didn't really have much in Objective-C.

What is there these days?

Comment: may I ask why are you trying GNU-step? I mean if you are targeting iOS, you still a mac device to release your game. and if you are not there are too many much more powerfull tools out there to create a game for mac (mostly in c++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an effort to make a cocos2d-iphone compatible that uses the gnustep library:
[cocos2d-GNUstep](https://github.com/ANindie/cocos2d-GNUstep)
You may find it useful but only if you plan to develop under linux and compile using mac...